# Inserir o valor de um atributo em um textBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Preciso inserir o valor do atributo `SALDO` da classe `Conta` em um **`TextBox`.**

Em java resgato via método `get` e converto com `parse.float` e seto como `string` no campo.

Em C# como executo?

Comment: Percebi que você é novo no site e decidi te dar umas dicas. 1. Você sempre pode deixar comentários em suas publicações. 2. Qualquer pergunta que você fizer, pode ter uma resposta marcada como correta (você marca a resposta usando o **✓** abaixo das setas para votar, no lado esquerdo da resposta). 3. Agora você pode votar positivamente em qualquer publicação do site que você achar útil (pergunta ou resposta). 4. Suas publicações podem ser formatadas usando _markdown_, existe uma caixa de ajuda para isso na tela onde se escreve a publicação. 5. Você pode [edit] suas publicações para melhorá-las.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É um pouco mais simples e intuitivo no C#.

Ao invés de usar métodos `get` e `set` é só atribuir e recuperar os valores destas propriedades (atributos). Quem se preocupa com  `get`'s e `set`'s é o compilador.

```
seuTextBox.Text = conta.Saldo.ToString();
```